# RStudio on Ubuntu - upgrade 1.1.364 results in "error occurred during transmission"

Tags: ubuntu, rstudio, transmission

After an upgrade to R users were experiencing the following error under RStudio:

> Error in .Call("rs_createGD") : C symbol name "rs_createGD" not in
>   load table

Researched and upgraded to the latest RStudio version

After upgrading RStudio none of the users can successfully connect

In the browser the error dialog RStudio Initialization Error is displayed with the "Error occurred during transmission"

Reviewing status I see the following errors:

> Sep 14 10:53:04 my.ip.here rserver[126421]: ERROR system error 13
>   (Permission denied)
>   [request-uri=/mathjax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML ]; OCCURRED
>   AT: void
>   rstudio::core::http::LocalStreamAsyncClient::handleConnect(const
>   rstudio_boost::system::error_code&) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/
>   cpp/core/include/core/http/LocalStreamAsyncClient.hpp:119; LOGGED
>   FROM: void
>   rstudio::server::session_proxy::{anonymous}::logIfNotConnectionTermina
>   ted(const rstudio::core::Error&, const rstudio::core::http::Request&)
>   /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/server/ServerSessionProxy.cpp:370 Sep 14
>   10:53:04 my.ip.here rserver[126421]: ERROR system error 13 (Permission
>   denied) [request-uri=/rpc/client_init]; OCCURRED AT: void rstudi
>   o::core::http::LocalStreamAsyncClient::handleConnect(const
>   rstudio_boost::system::error_code&)
>   /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/core/include/core/http/
>   LocalStreamAsyncClient.hpp:119; LOGGED FROM: void
>   rstudio::server::session_proxy::{anonymous}::logIfNotConnectionTerminated(const
>   rstudio::core::Er ror&, const rstudio::core::http::Request&)
>   /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/server/ServerSessionProxy.cpp:370 Sep 14
>   10:53:05 my.ip.here rserver[126421]: ERROR system error 13 (Permission
>   denied) [request-uri=/rpc/client_init]; OCCURRED AT: void rstudi
>   o::core::http::LocalStreamAsyncClient::handleConnect(const
>   rstudio_boost::system::error_code&)
>   /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/core/include/core/http/
>   LocalStreamAsyncClient.hpp:119; LOGGED FROM: void
>   rstudio::server::session_proxy::{anonymous}::logIfNotConnectionTerminated(const
>   rstudio::core::Er ror&, const rstudio::core::http::Request&)
>   /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/server/ServerSessionProxy.cpp:370

Running latest version 1.0.153 but have also removed and installed the latest pre-release candidate 1.1.364.  Both exhibit the same behaviour

Looking for downgrade versions now to see if that will resolve

Any suggestions/resolution much appreciated